# single-product.php not opening

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy, singlepage

I have created a set of pages. In first page product.php all the custom categories are shown (title and image). If a user clicks on it then it moves to the taxonomy-product_categories page where products are shown of the specific category. Now i want that if user clicks on the product then it goes to single-product.php page.

**code is here**

```
<?php
get_header();
$slug = get_queried_object()->slug; // get clicked category slug
$name = get_queried_object()->name; // get clicked category name
$tax_post_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products', // your post type
    'posts_per_page' => 999,
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_categories', // your taxonomy
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $slug
        )
    )
);
?>
<div id="main-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <?php
        $counter = 1;
        $tax_post_qry = new WP_Query($tax_post_args);
        if ($tax_post_qry->have_posts()) {
            while ($tax_post_qry->have_posts()) {
                $tax_post_qry->the_post();
                $the_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), $type);
                //var_dump($the_url);


                if ($counter % 4 == 0) {
                    echo '<div class="row product-gallery">';
                }
                ?>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="product-warp">
                        <div class="product">
                            <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $the_url[0] ?>" title="" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-name">
                            <h5>
                                <a href="">
                                    <?php echo get_the_title();
                                    ; ?>
                                </a>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                if ($counter % 4 == 0) {
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                ?>

                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**this is the place where user clicks then it should go to single-product.php**

```
<a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $the_url[0] ?>" title=""
```

Somebody guide me step by step please

Comment: Are you using any specific shop or? Woocommerce, jigoshop...?

Comment: no. i am not using these

Comment: If `product` is a CPT, then just calling `get_permalink()` should point to `single-product.php`.

Comment: it shows the page empty

Comment: try to add href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" also change permalink from setting menu and try

Comment: Well did you create `single-product.php` page with stuff in it? Try resetting the permalinks (flushing them).

Comment: yes i have created this

Comment: and i have data in it...it gets the single.php file not single-product.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `post_type => products` Then your file name must be like this `single-products.php`

Read this [article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates)

**And for precautions (if the page not open yet. means give 404 error)** go to

> 1. admin panel
> 2. settings
> 3. permalinks

First save permalinks as plain and refresh your site home page.

Then save permalinks as `post_name` and again refresh your home page

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try

```
'post_type' => 'products'
```

Your Post type is  “products”.
And wordpress ruls is “`single-{post_type}.php`”.
You make “`single-products.php`” and remove “`single-product.php`”

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

Comment: yes , it works. but in the single-products.php it shows the title not the content of the page.

Comment: you use get_the_content();

Comment: You use "echo get_the_content();" or "the_content();"